# removing words from a list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I´m trying to remove unnecessary words (an, a, the) from a list

```
Test = ['a', 'an', 'the', 'love']
unWantedWords = ['a', 'an', 'the']
RD1 = [x for x in Test if x != unWantedWords]
print(RD1)
output ->['a', 'an', 'the', 'love']
```

what is wrong w/ this?

Comment: Another hint: do not use capitalized variables... they are used for classes (see PEP8 - Style Guide for Python Code: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are comparing the value x to the entire list unWantedWords.

```
RD1 = [x for x in Test if x != unWantedWords]
```

Replace != with not in to check if x is... not in!

```
RD1 = [x for x in Test if x not in unWantedWords]
```

Comment: Doesn't this list comprehension have quadratic complexity? I suspect it would be better to convert `unWantedWords` into a set first so that the `in` test is `O(1)`.

Comment: Quite probably. The only issue might be if the words in the list aren't guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Thanks guys! I looked up in the SO and found a function to make the list unique, so first I need to remove duplicates and then remove unwanted words right?

Comment: If possible you'd want to just have Test as a set in the first place. Otherwise you can create a new set from the list using the set constructor; e.g testset = set(Test)

Answer (score 4):

```
RD1 = [x for x in Test if x not in unWantedWords]
```

unWantedWords is an array and you are comapring your words with an array that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind:

1. removing duplicates
2. preserving the original order

you can simply use 'set' (here is the core algorithm):

```
>>> Test = ['a', 'an', 'the', 'love']
>>> unWantedWords = ['a', 'an', 'the']
>>> print set(Test) - set(unWantedWords)
set(['love'])

>>> print list(set(Test) - set(unWantedWords))
['love']
```

This has the advantage of an optimized complexity.

Of course you can wrap this code in order to keep duplicates and order...

Comment: So you used set difference concept?? I think efficient too

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, set operations are often the best for this kind of purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong.

```
RD1 = [x for x in Test if x != unWantedWords]
```

your condition of **if x != unWantedWords** checks if x is equal to the list unWantedWords, instead of checking if x exists or not in unWantedWords.

The condition always is true because x is a string and not a list. Therefore all  your words are added to the list.

The correct idiom would be **if x not in unWantedWords**.

You can do, `RD1 = [x for x in Test if x not in set(unWantedWords)]`